# Sending http request through an open Browser

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to get some values out of the response of a call to our server at work. Now the problem I'm facing is that if I send the same request through a browser, preferably Firefox, in which I'm logged into the application it send back the correct response but if I try the same within a Browser Session where I'm not logged in I get redirected to the Log In Page. The same happens if I try to set off the request directly via the HttpUrlConnection class. To circumvent the problem I want to send the request through the open Browser session. This is the code I'm currently using:

```
    String callPage() {
    URL url;
    String Address = "NoValidResponse";
    try {
        url = new URL(getMapWidgetURL()); //function delivers the request URL
        HttpURLConnection Connect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();   
        //Connect.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        Connect.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Connect.getInputStream()));
        String Source = "";
        String Line;
        while((Line = in.readLine()) != null){
            Source += Line;
            System.out.println(Line);
        }
        System.out.println(Source);
        String[] SourceSplitted = Source.split(","); 
        for (int Zaehler = 0; Zaehler < SourceSplitted.length; Zaehler++) {
            if (SourceSplitted[Zaehler].contains("searchaddress")) { 
                SourceSplitted[Zaehler] = Address;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid URL");
        return Address; // Returns"NoValidResponse"
    }
    return Address; 
}
```

Comment: This for loop seems useless as you ar returning always "NoValidResponse"

Comment: Can you not programmatically login?

Comment: Sadly I can't, it´s part of an automated Test and I either need to open a new Instance of my Selenium WebDriver, which wields the same problem, or I need to leave the Page in the Instance I'm in which leads to a fairly long line of follow up problems.

Comment: Okay, I've found a Work around by grabbing the cookies of my current session and adding them via .setRequestProperty() to the outgoing request. Not exactly the way I wanted but it works for now.